# Pass data between 2 handler-functions without form-, URL-, or query-parameters in Golang?

Tags: go, web-applications, httphandler

I have the following example: (a "quiz" with 3 phases; only after the 3rd phase should all combined points get stored in the database)

1. GET-method (.com/play/phase1), consists of a form. User got 5 points. Total: 5
2. GET-method (.com/play/phase2), consists of a form. User got 3 points. Total: 8 (5+3)
3. GET-method (.com/play/phase3), consists of a form. User got 13 points. Total: 21 (5+3+13)
4. Points get stored in a database

How do I transfer the points from one handler-function to another? I understand retrieving values from forms, URL, or query. Should I perhaps pass it through as a query-parameter? (.com/play/phase2?points=5)

How do I do this in **Go**?

Comment: If you pass points as a query parameter, it would be easy to pass the quiz without solving it. Either set a cookie and store points in there, or after every submission store the partial result in your database.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks that makes sense. I'm using [this](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs) library for sessions, am I correct in the assumption that I should set points with [Put](https://godoc.org/github.com/alexedwards/scs#SessionManager.Put) and retrieve points with [Get](https://godoc.org/github.com/alexedwards/scs#SessionManager.Get) or [Pop](https://godoc.org/github.com/alexedwards/scs#SessionManager.Pop)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two choices of passing the data to your different handlers between subsequent requests:

1. Make the Go app store the values. Either in memory or a database. Here you'll have to figure out how to associate a given user to the stored values. This could be done via a browser session cookie with randomly generated ID. You could also pass this random session ID via querystring parameter if you find that easier. The gist is to have a sticky value associated with all requests of a user so you can use that as a key when looking up the corresponding data.
2. You can give the result back to the browser in the HTTP response and let the browser then pass it on in the next request as you alluded. This can be done in many ways like querystring, URL, POST body or cookie. The improtant thing to keep in mind here is that the user can forge/manipulate this data easily. The only way to prevent this is by signing or encrypting the data so the backend can be sure that it was not modified by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the points in an in-memory cache map like https://github.com/dgraph-io/ristretto with a key like `username+phase1` as a key and their points as the value in the map. You can also specify how long the value needs to be in cache with the https://godoc.org/github.com/dgraph-io/ristretto#Cache.SetWithTTL method in case your quiz has an expiration time.